# How to properly install Docker on sles 12?

Tags: linux, docker, suse

I want to install Docker in my VM which is in my physical local machine. VM contains sles 12.

I refer [install docker on suse and open suse](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/SUSE/) link. Now Docker is installed in my VM but I'm unable to run further commands because of issues.

**commands and it's output -**

1. docker -v

> Docker version 1.12.3, build 8eab29e

2. sudo service docker status

> hp:/var/run # sudo service docker status
>           docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
>
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
>          Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2016-12-08 16:04:35 IST; 6min ago
>
> Docs: http://docs.docker.com
>         Process: 11950 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd /run/containerd/containerd.sock --add-runtime oci=/usr/sbin/runc
>   --default-runtime oci $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Main PID: 11950 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Dec 08 16:04:35 hp dockerd[11950]: /usr/bin/dockerd:
>   /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02: version `DM_1_02_97' not found (required
>   by /usr/bin/dockerd)
>
> Dec 08 16:04:35 hp systemd[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/SUSE/): docker.service start request repeated
>   too quickly, refusing to start.
>
> Dec 08 16:04:35 hp systemd[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/SUSE/): Failed to start Docker Application
>   Container Engine.

3. systemctl status docker.socket

> docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
>
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; disabled)
>
> Active: active (listening) since Thu 2016-12-08 16:13:18 IST; 5s ago
>   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)   Process: 11977
>   ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock
>   (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

4. sudo docker run hello-world

> docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer.
>   See 'docker run --help'.

I am unable to identify what exactly goes wrong. How I can fix this issues or installing docker from the scratch?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's related to what discussed [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17846) , although related to an older version.

Try to:

1. Stop docker daemon
2. sudo rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db
3. Start docker daemon

Comment: @gile- It is not helpfull in my case. local-kv.db file is also not available on my system. /var/lib/docker/ directory is empty in my case.

Comment: If you still didn't try it, start docker daemon with "sudo systemctl start docker" . Can you post the output of "sudo systemctl status docker" ?

Comment: @gile- Already posted in "sudo service docker status". this command is instead of "sudo systemctl status docker".

Comment: It seems the reason of the failure is "Dec 08 16:04:35 hp dockerd[11950]: /usr/bin/dockerd: /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02: version `DM_1_02_97' not found (required by /usr/bin/dockerd) ". Check libdevmapper.so version and, if the case, try upgrading it, fro example from https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libdevmapper.so.1.02(DM_1_02_97)

Comment: @gile- while installing docker it skips docker b'coz it doesn't find any metadata on specified url. what is the correct url then so it can get metadata from that?